# can't set cookies from component sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

i try to create language switcher by create componant that call form action of front pate to set the cookies the problem is i don't see cookies in application tab

this is form that i use for switch language

```html
//lib/components/header.svele
<form action="/?/setLang" method="post" use:enhance>
    <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="th" />
    <button class=" menu" aria-current="page">
        <img src="{staticRoot}/assets/img/th.png" alt="Thai Language" />
    </button>
</form>
<form action="/?/setLang" method="post" use:enhance>
    <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en" />
    <button class="menu" aria-current="page">
        <img src="{staticRoot}/assets/img/en.png" alt="English Language" />
    </button>
</form>
```

and this is page.server

```js
//+page.server.js
export const load = async ({ cookies }) => {
    const currentLang = cookies.get('lang');
    if (!currentLang) {
        cookies.set('lang', 'en', {
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1
        });
    }
};

export const actions = {
    setLang: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const lang = formData.get('lang');
        cookies.set('lang', lang, {
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1
        });
        return { succes: true };
    }
};
```

i try to log out it look like when i click the button it call action success input is right after cookies.set i use cookies.get to check it good and the the page load is kick in and currentLang in load get undefined